# Using HMAC as a generic

Tags: rust, hmac

I am having trouble updating the crates `hmac` and `digest`. I have a function defined that takes a generic type of a HMAC function, and computes the HMAC over a given input. I have a function working with the version of `hmac` and `digest` being 0.7 and 0.8 respectively. However, I'm getting blocked when trying to get the same logic running for the latest versions 0.10 and 0.9 respectively.

In my machine, I use `rustc 1.48.0 (7eac88abb 2020-11-16)`.

The working example has the following `Cargo.toml` dependencies

```rust
[dependencies]
hmac = "0.7"
sha2 = "0.8"
digest = "0.8"
```

The minimal working example is the following:

```rust
use sha2::{Sha256};
use hmac::{Mac, Hmac};

type HmacSha256 = Hmac<Sha256>;
use digest::generic_array::typenum::{U32};

pub struct Key([u8; 2]);

impl Key {
    pub fn print_hmac<D>(&self, message: &[u8])
    where
        D: Mac<OutputSize = U32>,
    {
        let mut mac = D::new_varkey(self.0.as_ref()).unwrap();
        mac.input(message);

        let result = mac.result();
        let code_bytes = result.code();
        println!("{:?}", code_bytes)
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let verif_key = Key([12u8, 33u8]);
    verif_key.print_hmac::<HmacSha256>(&[83u8, 123u8]);
}
```

The above code works well, and compiles. However, when I try to upgrade the dependencies to the latests versions, everything breaks.

Updated `Cargo.toml`:

```rust
[dependencies]
hmac = "0.10"
sha2 = "0.9"
digest = "0.9"
```

With the updates, we have some changes in the nomenclature:

```
.input() -> .update()
.result() -> .finalize()
.code() -> .into_bytes()
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error

`no function or associated item named 'new_varkey' found for type parameter 'D' in the current scope`

So I tried to define the generic type to be `NewMac` (for that need to change the second line to `use hmac::{Mac, Hmac, NewMac};`). However, now the error is in the functions `.update()` and `.finalize()`.

I've also tried to pass the Digest generic type, rather than the Hmac, as follows:

```rust
pub fn print_hmac<D>(&self, message: &[u8])
    where
        D: Digest,
    {
        let mut mac = Hmac::<D>::new_varkey(self.0.as_ref()).unwrap();
        mac.update(message);

        let result = mac.finalise();
        let code_bytes = result.into_bytes();
        println!("{:?}", code_bytes)
    }
```

But still not working.

How should I handle the generic Hmac function for the updated crates?

Sorry for the long post, and I hope I made my problem clear. Thanks community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good to look at example code which is updated across version updates, and luckily `hmac` has [some tests](https://github.com/RustCrypto/MACs/blob/master/hmac/tests/lib.rs) in its repository.

Those tests use the `new_test` macro defined [here](https://github.com/RustCrypto/traits/blob/master/crypto-mac/src/dev.rs#L8) in the `crypto-mac` crate. In particular, there is one line similar to yours...

```rust
let mut mac = <$mac as NewMac>::new_varkey(key).unwrap();
```

...which suggests that `D` should be cast to a `NewMac` implementor in your code as well.

After implementing the nomenclature updates you've already identified, your code works with the additional `as NewMac` cast from above, as well as the corresponding new `+ NewMac` trait bound on `D`:

```rust
use sha2::{Sha256};
use hmac::{NewMac, Mac, Hmac};

type HmacSha256 = Hmac<Sha256>;
use digest::generic_array::typenum::{U32};

pub struct Key([u8; 2]);

impl Key {
    pub fn print_hmac<D>(&self, message: &[u8])
    where
        D: Mac<OutputSize = U32> + NewMac,       // `+ NewMac` input trait bound
    {
        let mut mac = <D as NewMac>::new_varkey(self.0.as_ref()).unwrap();     // `as NewMac` cast
        mac.update(message);

        let result = mac.finalize();
        let code_bytes = result.into_bytes();
        println!("{:?}", code_bytes)
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let verif_key = Key([12u8, 33u8]);
    verif_key.print_hmac::<HmacSha256>(&[83u8, 123u8]);
}
```